# Why does webclient.downloadstring fail with a 503 error? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, http-status-code-503, webclient

I have the following code which I'm using to scrap links from google (for later processing).

```
Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient()


Dim html As String
html = wc.DownloadString(URL)
```

The URL is a string value - a typical value is:

```
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=qwerty&biw=1228&bih=612&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:27/01/2015,cd_max:28/01/2015&tbm=#q=qwerty&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:27/01/2015,cd_max:28/01/2015&start=0
```

Whenever I copy this into my browser it works no problem. Sometimes when I try and run this through webclient it fails with a 503 error, sometimes it succeeds.

Any advice would be great!

Comment: I tested your exact code with the exact url you posted and it works fine. Is it maybe another url you are having problems with?

Comment: This error seems to be transient (It works occasionally on my machine too). I'll add that to the question.

Comment: I literally just ran this 100 times in a row as a loop and each and every request worked as expected (I checked for the existence of a string that was in the search results). I'm wondering if it is maybe a problem related to your network or pc. Is there any other code that could be interfering with this request? The code as you posted it works fine every time.

Comment: Could you run 1,000? Whenever I get it working it fails around 500,

Comment: Just ran it 1000 in a row with a 3 second delay in between each request and all worked fine (took almost an hour). I have 2 more questions, 1) Do you have any delay between requests or are you just hammering requests out as fast as possible? 2) When you do get the 503 error does it seem to continue happening after that or do you only seem to get one 503 error per 500 requests?

Comment: 1) no delay currently (other than some very minor processing time). 2) continually getting the 503 after it starts. Thanks for your help with this btw.